# Instagram API load media of following or home page

Tags: php, javascript, oauth, instagram

I am making an Instagram app. I have login and access tokens working and I can request data. However I do not know how to load the feed that a user would see in their home page on the app. I can search for pictures based on location + time, I can load a specific users posts and I can load the users posts. Is there a 'home' feed I can read?

Comment: I dunno, http://whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: @SomeKittens I don't see any problems with his question..

Comment: I already said that I tried to find the way to do this, its not a technical question its a general question on how to query instagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, there is. Just issue a call to

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

as described in the [User Endpoints documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed).